# C++ std::make_shared memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm having memory leak problems with the following line of code:

```
auto state = newSpriteState();
```

Where these are the related functions:

```
class SpriteState {
    protected:
        Vector3 position;
        int width, height;
        double rotation, scaling;
        int priority;

    public:
        SpriteState()
            : position(0,0,0),
            width(1), height(1),
            rotation(0), scaling(1.0f),
            priority(0)
        {}

    std::shared_ptr<SpriteState> newSpriteState()
    {
        return std::make_shared<SpriteState>();
    }
};

class Vector3 {
private:
    double x, y, z;

public:
    Vector3( double x_, double y_, double z_ )
    {
        x = x_; y = y_; z = z_;
    }
};
```

Intel Inspector continues to report that I'm having a memory leak in 
the function `newSpriteState()`; more specifically `std::make_shared<SpriteState>()`.

### UPDATE

Judging from the comments, it seems there may be some external reason for this so here's more code:

```
bool Sprite::loadImage() {
    auto state = newSpriteState();
    initStateVector(0, state);
}
```

where:

```
class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite();

    std::map<const int, const std::shared_ptr<SpriteState>> stateVector;

    void initStateVector(const int line, std::shared_ptr<SpriteState>& state)
    { 
        stateVector.clear(); 
        stateVector.insert(std::make_pair( line, std::move(state) )); 
    }

    void loadImage();
}
```

I've uploaded a simplified version of the `Sprite` class I'm actually using for clarity.

Basically, I'm allocating a `shared_ptr<SpriteState>` and sticking into a `std::map` in class `Sprite`.

Comment: What happens to `state` after you created it? Is it stored somewhere in an object that itself isn't de-allocated properly?

Comment: Do you keep direct or indirect global references to `SpriteState`s?

Comment: When it reports this leak, is it before or after you let the shared pointer go out of scope (or `reset` it)? If you never `reset` the shared pointer and never let it go out of scope, then that will cause the memory allocated in `newSpriteState` to leak, but that's not `newSpriteState`'s fault.

Comment: @K-ballo I stick SpriteState references into a map. I've uploaded some more code to show what I'm doing.

Comment: @dk123: My question is this: Is there any _global object_ of type `std::shared_ptr<SpriteState>`, or that directly or indirectly contain `std::shared_ptr<SpriteState>`s?

Comment: @K-ballo No there is none. The only thing keeping reference to std::shared_ptr<SpriteState> s is the local map within Sprite.

Comment: @dk123: And there are no global `Sprite`s, nor objects that directly or indirectly contain `Sprite`s?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not really quite sure when the report is happening. Intel Inspector just gives me a list of leak errors once I shut the program down. I've uploaded a slight bit more code just to show that I'm creating 'state' within a function call. Do I need to be calling reset explicitly within it?

Comment: Are there any `Sprite` objects in existence when you shut your program down?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I keep a global `unique_ptr<Sprite> font` object for this, which I call a `font.reset(nullptr);` in one of my program destructor calls. Which is mainly why I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: @K-ballo  I keep a global `unique_ptr<Sprite> font` object for which I call a `font.reset(nullptr);` in one of my program destructor calls.

Comment: @dk123: What is a _"program destructor call"_? It may be too late for _Intel Inspector_ to notice...

Comment: @K-ballo Basically this is a DLL which I've encapsulated as a single object. When the program shuts down it should call the object's destructor where I've placed the `font.reset(nullptr);`. If there aren't any more answers I guess I might have to take your advice and take into consideration that it might have been too late for _Intel Inspector_ to notice..

Comment: Confirm that the destructor got called.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've confirmed through the debugger. Which is really why I don't understand this..

Comment: Is `font` the only `Sprite` object or object derived from `Sprite`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There are other `shared_ptr<Sprite>`s. These seem to get removed fine without leaks; it's just this global `unique_ptr<Sprite> font` object I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved after an upgrade to vs12. My best estimation is that the problem had something to do with the tr1 implementation of smart pointers.